Structured Data type conversion produce extra dimension
So I'm trying to write a numpy array to a binary PLY file, type convertion is required. What I did was
A = array([0.        , 0.00333476, 0.29804176, 0.66598558])
A.astype([('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

Output:
array([(0, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ),
       (0, 0.00333476, 0.00333476, 0.00333476),
       (0, 0.29804176, 0.29804176, 0.29804176),
       (0, 0.6659856 , 0.6659856 , 0.6659856 )],
      dtype=[('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

Expecting:
array((0, 0.00333476, 0.29804176, 0.6659856), dtype=[('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

Btw, I'm on numpy version '1.24.4', is this a bug?

Use np.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured

astype does not add a dimension.  shape remains (4,).

Your array and desired dtype:
In [489]: A = np.array([0.        , 0.00333476, 0.29804176, 0.66598558])
     ...: dt = np.dtype([('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

In [490]: A
Out[490]: array([0.        , 0.00333476, 0.29804176, 0.66598558])

As you note astype puts one number in all fields of a record, resulting in as many records as elements of A:
In [491]: A.astype(dt)
Out[491]: 
array([(0, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ),
       (0, 0.00333476, 0.00333476, 0.00333476),
       (0, 0.29804176, 0.29804176, 0.29804176),
       (0, 0.6659856 , 0.6659856 , 0.6659856 )],
      dtype=[('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

The correct way to provide data to a compound dtype is to  write all values for one record in a tuple, or a list of tuples for 1d structured array:
In [493]: A1 = np.array([(0.        , 0.00333476, 0.29804176, 0.66598558)], dtype=dt); A1
Out[493]: 
array([(0, 0.00333476, 0.29804176, 0.6659856)],
      dtype=[('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

recfunctions module has a convenience function that can convert A to structured:
In [494]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf

In [495]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(A,dt)
Out[495]: 
array((0, 0.00333476, 0.29804176, 0.6659856),
      dtype=[('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

So here a 1d array converts to a 0d, one record structured array.
People also try to use view.  Since A.dtype is 'F8', that produces 2 records (with 4 byte elements):
In [499]: A.view(dt)
Out[499]: 
array([(          0, 0.       , -5.4416844e-17, 0.9192123),
       (-1090341701, 1.6490208, -3.0346762e+37, 1.7914963)],
      dtype=[('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

If I first make a 'f4' array then I get a better result - but note it is 1d.  view has added a leading dimension.  unstructured_to_structured takes care of these messy details.
In [500]: A.astype('f4').view(dt)
Out[500]: 
array([(0, 0.00333476, 0.29804176, 0.6659856)],
      dtype=[('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

Another way is to convert each row of a 2d array into a tuple, and use the list of tuples method:
In [504]: np.array([tuple(i) for i in [A]] , dt)
Out[504]: 
array([(0, 0.00333476, 0.29804176, 0.6659856)],
      dtype=[('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

edit
Your astype produces the same thing as:
In [507]: np.array(A, dt)
Out[507]: 
array([(0, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ),
       (0, 0.00333476, 0.00333476, 0.00333476),
       (0, 0.29804176, 0.29804176, 0.29804176),
       (0, 0.6659856 , 0.6659856 , 0.6659856 )],
      dtype=[('idx', '<i4'), ('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])

A has to be a tuple (or list of tuples) to fill the dt records as you want.

Thank you! This has been troubling me for days. However, is the ".astype" method behaving as intended though? From my understanding, the first two methods should be interchangeable.

astype changes each element of A into a dt object.  The shape remains the same.  You expect instead that because A has 4 elements it would make one dt record. Using a compound dtype is not the same as adding a dimension. Devs explicitly chose the tuple notation to reduce this confusion.
